# How to change XAML elemen't template from code-behind?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have next button's style defined in resources:

```
<Style x:Key="OKBtn" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Grid>
                    <Rectangle .../>

                    <TextBlock x:Name="Text" ..>
                        <Run Language="en-en" Text="OK"/>
                    </TextBlock>                        
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

And I want in some specified case from code change Button's text.

I.e. change "OK" (`<Run Language="en-en" Text="OK"/>`) to "Accept".
How can I do that?

Is it possible to access this TextBlock "Text" and change content exactly for my one button, but not for all OK buttons?

My button:

```
<Button x:Name="OkButton" Style="{DynamicResource OKBtn}" />
```

Comment: Are you using MVVM Pattern now, why you want to change the template's  properties using code-behind,I think that't not a good idea for WPF.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can borrow some props from template `Template`, for example `Tag` property. So the `TextBlock` text in the `ControlTemplate` should be like this.

```
<Run Language="en-en" Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}, Path=Tag}"/>
```

And you can change the button caption by setting it's `Tag` property.

```
OkButton.Tag = "Accept";
```

And for not set all button texts manually you can create some `ValueConverter` to set `TextBlock` text in the `ControlTemplate` to the "Ok" whenever `Tag` property is empty.

Answer (score 0):

At first, you should declare `ContentPresenter` to show any object in your `Content` property of `Button` control.

```
<Style x:Key="OkBtn" TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Rectangle/>
                    <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding Path=Content, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Button}}}"></ContentPresenter>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Then, it is possible to set another `Content` by using `code behind` or `binding`:

By code behind:

```
okButton.Content="desirableText";
```

By binding:

```
<Button x:Name="OkButton" Style="{DynamicResource OKBtn}" Content="{Binding FooText}" />

private string fooText;

public string FooText
{
   get { return fooText; }
   set
   {
       fooText = value;
       OnPropertyChanged("FooText");
   }
}
```